# Preventing overflow of large integers in (GPU) optimized methods such as gmpy2 and numba

Tags: python, gpu, largenumber, gmpy

I am trying to check whether a large integer is a perfect square using `gmpy2` in a JIT-decorated (optimized) routine using `numba`. The example here is for illustrative purposes only (from a theoretical point of view, such equations or elliptic curves can be treated differently/better). My code seems to overflow since it yields solutions that aren't really ones:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
import gmpy2
from gmpy2 import mpz, xmpz

import time
import sys

@jit('void(uint64)')
def findIntegerSolutionsGmpy2(limit: np.uint64):
    for x in np.arange(0, limit+1, dtype=np.uint64):
        y = mpz(x**6-4*x**2+4)
        if gmpy2.is_square(y):
            print([x,gmpy2.sqrt(y),y])

def main() -> int:
    limit = 100000000
    start = time.time()
    findIntegerSolutionsGmpy2(limit)
    end = time.time()
    print("Time elapsed: {0}".format(end - start))
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Using a `limit = 1000000000` the routine finishes within approx. **4 seconds**. The limit, which I am handing over to the decorated function, will not exceed an unsigned integer of 64 Bit (which seems not to be an issue here).

I read that big integers do not work in combination with numba's JIT optimization (see for example [here](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/5005)).

***My Question:***
Is there any possibility to use large integers in (GPU) optimized code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real reason of wrong results is simple, you forgot to convert `x` to `mpz`, so statement `x ** 6 - 4 * x ** 2 + 4` is promoted to `np.uint64` type and computed with overflow (because `x` in statement is `np.uint64`). Fix is trivial, just add `x = mpz(x)`:

```py
@jit('void(uint64)', forceobj = True)
def findIntegerSolutionsGmpy2(limit: np.uint64):
    for x in np.arange(0, limit+1, dtype=np.uint64):
        x = mpz(x)
        y = mpz(x**6-4*x**2+4)
        if gmpy2.is_square(y):
            print([x,gmpy2.sqrt(y),y])
```

also in you may notice that I added `forceobj = True`, this is to suppress Numba compilation warnings at start.

After this fix everything works fine and you don't see wrong results.

If your task is to check if expression gives strict square then I decided to invent and implement another solution for you, code below.

It works as following. You may notice that if a number is square then it is also square modulus any number (taking modulus is `x % N` operation).

We can take any number, for example product of some primes, `K = 2 * 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19`. Now we can make a simple filter, compute all squares modulo K, mark this squares inside bit vector and then check what numbers modulo K have ones in this filter bit vector.

Filter K (product of primes), mentioned above, leaves only 1% of candidates for squares. We can also do a second stage, apply same filter with other primes, e.g. `K2 = 23 * 29 * 31 * 37 * 41`. This will filter them even mor by 3%. In total we will have `1% * 3% = 0.03%` amount remaining of initial candidates.

After two filterings only few numbers remain to be checked. They can be easily fast-checked with `gmpy2.is_square()`.

Filtering stage can be easily wrapped into Numba function, as I did below, this function can have extra Numba param `parallel = True`, this will tell Numba to automatically run all Numpy operations in parallel on all CPU cores.

In code I use `limit = 1 << 30`, this signifies limit of all `x` to be checked, and I use `block = 1 << 26`, this signifies how many numbers to check at a time, in parallel Numba function. If you have enough memory you may set `block` to be larger to occupy all CPU cores more efficiently. block of size `1 << 26` approximately uses around 1 GB of memory.

After using my idea with filtering and using multi-core CPU my code solves same task as yours hundred times faster.

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow70664185#main.py)

```py
import numpy as np, numba

@numba.njit('u8[:](u8[:], u8, u8, u1[:])', cache = True, parallel = True)
def do_filt(x, i, K, filt):
    x += i; x %= K
    x2 = x
    x2 *= x2;     x2 %= K
    x6 = x2 * x2; x6 %= K
    x6 *= x2;     x6 %= K
    x6 += np.uint64(4 * K + 4)
    x2 <<= np.uint64(2)
    x6 -= x2; x6 %= K
    y = x6
    #del x2
    filt_y = filt[y]
    filt_y_i = np.flatnonzero(filt_y).astype(np.uint64)
    return filt_y_i

def main():
    import math
    gmpy2 = None
    import gmpy2
    
    Int = lambda x: (int(x) if gmpy2 is None else gmpy2.mpz(x))
    IsSquare = lambda x: gmpy2.is_square(x)
    Sqrt = lambda x: Int(gmpy2.sqrt(x))
    
    Ks = [2 * 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19,    23 * 29 * 31 * 37 * 41]
    filts = []
    for i, K in enumerate(Ks):
        a = np.arange(K, dtype = np.uint64)
        a *= a
        a %= K
        filts.append((K, np.zeros((K,), dtype = np.uint8)))
        filts[-1][1][a] = 1
        print(f'filter {i} ratio', round(len(np.flatnonzero(filts[-1][1])) / K, 4))
    
    limit = 1 << 30
    block = 1 << 26
    
    for i in range(0, limit, block):
        print(f'i block {i // block:>3} (2^{math.log2(i + 1):>6.03f})')
        x = np.arange(0, min(block, limit - i), dtype = np.uint64)
        
        for ifilt, (K, filt) in enumerate(filts):
            len_before = len(x)
            x = do_filt(x, i, K, filt)
            print(f'squares filtered by filter {ifilt}:', round(len(x) / len_before, 4))
        
        x_to_check = x
        print(f'remain to check {len(x_to_check)}')
        
        sq_x = []
        for x0 in x_to_check:
            x = Int(i + x0)
            y = x ** 6 - 4 * x ** 2 + 4
            if not IsSquare(y):
                continue
            yr = Sqrt(y)
            assert yr * yr == y
            sq_x.append((int(x), int(yr)))
        print('squares found', len(sq_x))
        print(sq_x)
        
        del x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
filter 0 ratio 0.0094
filter 1 ratio 0.0366
i block   0 (2^ 0.000)
squares filtered by filter 0: 0.0211
squares filtered by filter 1: 0.039
remain to check 13803
squares found 2
[(0, 2), (1, 1)]
i block   1 (2^24.000)
squares filtered by filter 0: 0.0211
squares filtered by filter 1: 0.0392
remain to check 13880
squares found 0
[]
i block   2 (2^25.000)
squares filtered by filter 0: 0.0211
squares filtered by filter 1: 0.0391
remain to check 13835
squares found 0
[]
i block   3 (2^25.585)
squares filtered by filter 0: 0.0211
squares filtered by filter 1: 0.0393
remain to check 13907
squares found 0
[]

...............................
```

Comment: Thank you for this great answer, especially for the alternative approach. Some days ago, I tried my first walking attempts with GPU, which results in [this CUDA-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70755606/how-do-i-parallelize-this-small-numba-script-of-a-large-already-cuda-runnable). Is it really the case that all threads do the same there, although I have optimized the block parameters `[128, 255]` by trial & error? My hope was that `numba` would split the work under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

I could now manage to avoid the loss of precision by the following code:

```
@jit('void(uint64)')
def findIntegerSolutionsGmpy2(limit: np.uint64):
    for x in np.arange(0, limit+1, dtype=np.uint64):
        x_ = mpz(int(x))**2
        y = x_**3-mpz(4)*x_+mpz(4)
        if gmpy2.is_square(y):
            print([x,gmpy2.sqrt(y),y])
```

But by using the `limit = 100000000` this ammended/fixed routine finishes not within **4 seconds** anymore. It took now **912 seconds**. Very likely we have an insurmountable gap between precision and speed.

Using CUDA it becomes faster, namely **5 minutes** (machine with 128GB RAM, an Intel Xeon CPU E5-2630 v4, 2.20GHz processor and two graphic cards of type Tesla V100 with 16GB RAM each), but I obtain along the correct results also wrong results again.

```
%%time
from numba import jit, cuda
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt

@cuda.jit
def findIntegerSolutionsCuda(arr):
    i=0
    for x in range(0, 1000000000+1):
        y = float(x**6-4*x**2+4)
        sqr = int(sqrt(y))
        if sqr*sqr == int(y):
            arr[i][0]=x
            arr[i][1]=sqr
            arr[i][2]=y
            i+=1

arr=np.zeros((10,3))
findIntegerSolutionsCuda[128, 255](arr)

print(arr)
```